# Codeigniter session not working properly when php upgraded to 7.1.1

Tags: session, codeigniter-3, php-7.1

The following code worked correctly in php 5*
in my controller:

```
        $admin_login_status= $this->admin_login->check_admin_login();

        if ($admin_login_status=='success')
        {

            // print_r($this->session->userdata());exit;

            redirect(ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH, 'refresh');exit;
        }
        else
        {
         //some condition
        }
```

And in my model i have set the session like this

```
     $query=some query
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $record = $query->row();


        //check active admin
        if($record->login_status==='active')
        {

        $secure_code = 'something';

        $pwd_hash = hash('sha512', $pass.$secure_code.$record->login_salt);

            if(strtolower($record->username)===strtolower($uname) && $record->password===$this->general->hash_password($pass,$record->login_salt))
        {


                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $login_string = hash('sha512', $record->username.$user_browser);

                $this->session->set_userdata('admin_user_id', $record->admin_id);
                $this->session->set_userdata('admin_user_name', $record->username);
                $this->session->set_userdata('admin_user_type', $record->role_id);
                $this->session->set_userdata('nickname', $record->username);
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_string', $login_string);
                // $this->session->set_userdata(ADMIN_USER_TYPE, $record->user_type); 

                $this->log_login_success($record);

                return "success";
```

Noe the problem is when i print_r the session value in that controller it printed everything Here it is:

```
    Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1501607438 [admin_user_id] => 2 [admin_user_name] => admin [admin_user_type] => 1 [nickname] => admin [login_string] => 269c55741765ce233f4880a11a06b03def9090a6494255371af22074159f4960f349f1fd93647b31ad31e15603a6e6ab0bbf3bb30672a5b8d8d573eebbe3f20b )
```

. But when i redirected in some Url and accessed the same session it just return this

```
    Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1501607438 )
```

It is returning the same value in previous version of php . The codeigniter version is 3.0.6 .Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you haven't set the session in your model because you have it commented out!